# Cuting borders of an image using GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

So I'm wondering if there is a way to do the following:
1. Upload an image
2. Remove the 20 pixel lower border the image has 
3. Save the image

Well, I can already do the easy steps (1 and 3) but I have no Idea how to do the third one. I was thinking maby using a [Transform](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/Transform.html) but Im not sure how to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [crop()](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions.html#Image_crop) method.
Your steps are:

1. Upload the image
2. Get the image size
3. Call crop()
4. Save the data

Comment: Okey so I got the image, and I cut the borders. Now I have a new Image object, right? so how do I save hat new Image object so that it overrides the previous Image?

Comment: @Woojah You can't override, you need to create a new blob on the blobstore with the new data and delete the old one.